# PostgreSQL with Python catching exceptions with plpy.SPIError

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, plpy

how to properly catch the exception with **plpy.SPIError**,
notation:

```
try:
    # code
except plpy.SPIError,e:
    plpy.notice(e)
```

results in an error

```
DETAIL: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 99)
```

PostgreSQL 9.2 ,

PL / Python 3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 3.x you've got to separate the exception from the variable with `as`:

```
try:
    pass
except plpy.SPIError as e:
    plpy.notice(e)
```

The reason for the change from the syntax supported in 2.x ("syntactic ambiguity") is discussed here: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/